# How to allow a single User to vote multiple times on a single Post with the 'acts_as_votable' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've installed the 'acts_as_votable' gem, and am able to vote successfully.  When I add the code from the documentation to be able to allow a single User to vote multiple times on a single Post it doesn't seem to work.

```
def upvote
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.first
    @video.upvote_by @user, :duplicate => true
    redirect_to :back
end

def downvote
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @video.downvote_by User.first, :duplicate => true
    redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: documentation says that you can use `duplicate: true` when calling `vote_by`. Looking at the source code, `upvote_by` seems to be an alias for `vote_up`, and `vote_up` calls `vote_by` but it never sends `duplicate` option to it. So, you can fix this by using `vote_by` instead, or make a PR as a feature to make those aliases pass the `duplicate` option.

Comment: Thank you very much!  If you would like to make an answer I would gladly mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Acts As Votable** documentation states that you can send `duplicate: true` to `vote_by` like:

```
@video.vote_by voter: @user, duplicate: true
```

Now, looking at the source code, it seems like `upvote_by` is an alias for `vote_up`[docs](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/aaabd191743859628e50276fb41bf5b003f0033b/lib/acts_as_votable/votable.rb#L15), and looking at [vote_up definition](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/aaabd191743859628e50276fb41bf5b003f0033b/lib/acts_as_votable/votable.rb#L119):

```
def vote_up(voter, options = {})
  self.vote_by voter: voter, vote: true, vote_scope: options[:vote_scope], vote_weight: options[:vote_weight]
end
```

it never passes `duplication` option to `vote_by`.

So, your solution would be to use `vote_by` instead.